# OSX "Open with..." bug

Tags: macos

Hello I have this kind of situation, I really think this should not be happening...?!

[image: osx bug]

how to leave only ONE "block" of choices?

OSX Version: 10.6.6 (had this bug earlier also)

Comment: how to paste screenshot? I pushed "img" button and uploaded a picture, and all I have is link to it..? Update: thnx daniel

Comment: Images have a leading `!` in Markdown, links don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebuild your LaunchServices database by entering the following command in the Terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

and then do a restart.

Comment: After doing this, you could also have Spotlight re-index your drive just to be sure.

Comment: you first user who helped me straight away without any nonsenses from all CommunityWiki sites! thnx Asmus =)

Comment: You'll lose some information though. At least file type associations (default applications) and which applications have been opened previously.